# How can I connect the MP503 to an Arduino Uno (Smoke, Alcohol Sensor)?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I don't know how I can connect an MP503 sensor to my Arduino.

Please help.

[image]
http://eleparts.co.kr/data/design/product_file/SENSOR/gas/MP503%20(Ver1.4)%20-%20Manual.pdf

Comment: link is broken, use this one: http://eleparts.co.kr/data/design/product_file/SENSOR/gas/MP503%20(Ver1.4)%20-%20Manual.pdf

Comment: you really do need to include more information: is it a raw component, part of a circuit, on a shield? What have you tried? Are you looking for how to connect to it electrically or programatically (or both)?

Comment: @frarugi87 - Your link appears to be broken as well... both links give 403 Forbidden :-( However, this one seems to work: http://eleparts.co.kr/data/design/product_file/SENSOR/gas/ZP01-MP503%20Air%20Quality%20Module%20V1.4.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Ok, first of all I doubt you will be able to get a lot of measurements with that. Because... I know that kind of sensors and you will quickly get tired of it.

Anyway, you have to connect

1. pin 1 to +5V
2. pin 2 to ground
3. pin 3 to +5V
4. pin 4 to a resistor towards ground. Value has to be determined.

To chose the value, you have to try. Change resistor values until, in fresh air, the voltage you can sense across the resistor is approx 1V. I think it is arount 10k, but you'll have to try

Chosen the resistor, you have to simply attach the node between pin 4 and the resistor to an analog input and then read the voltage.

Now you have to calibrate the sensor. Put it in a fixed-concentration gas and measure the voltage: `nCalib = analogRead(sensorPin);`.

Then, when you need to measure the concentration, you just have to read the voltage again with `nMeas = analogRead(sensorPin);`. The factor Rs/Ro can be calculated with the formula

```
Rs_over_Ro = nCalib / (1024 - nCalib) * (1024 - nMeas) / nMeas;
```

Once you have the factor, look at the graph in figure 3 to get the concentration:

[image: figure 3: sensitivity for Mp503]

As I told you, I think you will quickly get tired of it, but this is how to use it.